# java: request.getSession().getAttribute is null

Tags: java, session, request

I have set an attribute in the session that I got from a CXF resource through the following code:

```
    HttpSession session = request.getSession(); 
    session.setAttribute("field", "testValue");
```

When I try to retrieve the value in the Servlet:

```
    request.getSession().getAttribute("field")
```

the returned value is null.
I've debugged the code and the session in the CXF resource has a different ID than the session in the servlet. However the browser session is the same.
Can anyone help me figure out how to get this fixed?
Thanks

Comment: I think is because you session expired that's why you are getting a null value.

Comment: That's not right, the session didn't expire. Between setting the attribute and getting it back is just a couple of seconds. The browser tab is absolutely the same but in debug I can see two different session IDs.

Comment: You could try `getSession(false)` instead of `getSession()`, just to make 100% sure that the session is not being recreated for some reason.

Comment: It's the same, still null.

Comment: Does anyone have a clue on what's going on here?

Comment: `HttpSession session = request.getSession(false); 
    session.setAttribute("field", "testValue");
  request.getSession(false).getAttribute("field");`
Can you Try with this?

Comment: @Gatusko It does not work, I have tried what you suggested. I don't know how to paste images in here but I would like to show you that in debug mode I have two different IDs for the sessions. isNew is false in both sessions, creation time is different, isValid is true for both, expiring is false for both. I think that a session retrieved in CXF is different to the session retrieved in the servlet. In that case, how can I work around it?

Comment: Can anyone tell me if CXF open a different version to HTTPServlet in the same browser?

Comment: I have the same problem using CDI.